# Masking password input from the console : Java with nohup command

Tags: java, linux, logging, jar, console

I have an application where i have disabled the echoing for the password field after hitting the following command:

```
java -cp testJar.jar testClassFileInJar username
```

where username is a parameter provided to the main method of the class testClassFileInJar. After hitting enter, password is prompted. When i try the following command i could not make it run and the java1.out file is also empty.

```
nohup java -cp testJar.jar testClassFileInJar username & > java1.out
```

Please suggest. To summarize, I need logging to be done in java1.out file and nohup command to be used with this java command.

I have used the following code in main method:

```
Console console = System.console();
String userName = args[0];
String password = String.valueOf(console.readPassword("Password: "));
//other code logic for processing username and password
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with nohup but nothing worked. I then configured logger to the application(`java.util.logging.Logger`) and used `screen` to run the following command.

```
java -cp testJar.jar testClassFileInJar username
```

In screen this command will prompt for the password.

Simply satisfied my requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
nohup java -cp testJar.jar testClassFileInJar username > java1.out &
```